# using unit tests to keep index.yaml updated

Tags: google-app-engine

So far the only way I have been able to keep index.yaml updated when I make code changes is to either hit the urls via browser or using TransparentProxy and the application is being served through dev_appserver.

This sucks.

Is there a way to bootstrap the appengine environment in the unit test runner so that what ever process is used to update the index.yaml can be run without incurring the overhead of the single threaded dev_appserver.

The difference is significant. My testsuite(80% coverage) runs at 2 minutes but does not update index.yaml, if I run the same suite using TransparentProxy to forward request to port 8080, the index.yaml does get updated but it takes about 4 hours. Again, this sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my Nose plugin for this, called [nose-gae-index](http://github.com/jkrebs/nose-gae-index). It uses the internal IndexYamlUpdater class from the SDK, so it is definitely better than proxying requests.

Despite this improvement, there is definitely no need to have it enabled all the time. I use it before deployment and to inspect changes to index configuration caused by new commits.

Remember not to use queries that require indexes in the tests themselves, or they will be added to the configuration file as well!

Comment: Joachim. You are a life saver, this has been a pain in my rear for months. I'm actually in the process of switching to py.test so I just took the meat of your plugin and made it a part of my setup/teardown. Thank you very much I wish I could up vote you more.